# Changing orientation of loading screen UIActivity Indicator

Tags: iphone, ios, loading

In my iPhone i used loading screen(Activity Indicator inside a UIView) and now i am converting my app to an universal app. So i want my loading screen to change with respect to the orientation of the device. i have attached the code

```
-(void) loading
{
waitingBGView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)];
[waitingBGView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[waitingBGView setAlpha:0.5];

[appdelegate.window addSubview:waitingBGView];

smallBlackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)/2 - 80, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)/2 - 30, 160.0, 60.0)];
smallBlackView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
smallBlackView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
smallBlackView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
smallBlackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
[smallBlackView addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

UILabel *lblLoading = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 0.0, 100.0, 60.0)];
lblLoading.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblLoading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
lblLoading.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblLoading.text = @"Loading...";

[smallBlackView addSubview:lblLoading];
[appdelegate.window addSubview:smallBlackView];
}
```

How to alter the code so that the view changes with respect to orientation of the device?

Comment: Try,     activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);

Answer (score 0):

```
 activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape ||self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {   
yourctivity.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center, self.view.center, 30, 30);
}
```

Hope this will help.